# Don't include an OpenSearch provider on nonexistent subdomains

Tags: feature-request

If you try to go to an SE site that doesn't exist, such as http://metae.stackexchange.com/, Chrome sees this in the page `<head>`:

```
<link rel="search" 
      type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
      title="Stack Exchange" 
      href="https://stackexchange.com/opensearch.xml" />
```

And so it dutifully installs a Chrome search provider for "Stack Exchange" with keyword "metae.stackexchange.com" and URL "https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%s". This is a little bit annoying, since it clutters up my list of search engines (I just went through my search engine settings and cleaned out around a dozen nonexistent fat-fingered Stack Exchange domains).

It would be nice if Stack Exchange would just not include the OpenSearch provider `<link />` tag on nonexistent *.stackexchange.com domains to begin with (i.e. those where the error page is titled "Site not found: foo.stackexchange.com").

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/276069/google-chrome-automatically-adding-websites-to-my-list-of-search-engines

Comment: @random What about it? I like OpenSearch providers in general, but I think this is one case where the site shouldn't provide an OpenSearch thingum in the first place.

Comment: Would you ask this of every site that triggers this behaviour, or just the ones that allow you to enter text into a box?